# Deploy Azure App Service and Webjobs using Azure Devops in .Net Framework

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

I have created Azure AppService and added Webjobs console application in a single solution. I'm trying to build the solution through Azure DevOps build pipeline and Deploy the package through Octopus. When I build the solution there files required for Appservice such as Web.config and Global.asax are missing from Artifacts folder. so When deploying that package is breaking the AppService.

I tried to change the MSBuild arguments while building the solution. the current MSBuild arguments are as follows:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
>   /p:Configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) /p:OutputPath=.\bin\ /p:PackageTempRootDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\temp" /p:packageAsSingleFile=true /p:TargetProfile=Cloud

I suspect, while building the Webjobs it is removing the App Service files, so the generated package does not contain all the required files. My Build pipeline looks like below.[image: Build Defination on Azure Devops]

My Artifacts folder Creates a Nupkg file which has following files.[image]

If the App Service is deployed alone, It is working fine,Please suggest me the way I can deploy both from single solution and one Build definition on Azure devOps.

Comment: So you just need Web.config and Global.asax files in artifact folder?

Comment: @Anna When I deploy the APP service alone then Web.config and Global.asax files are present in the Azure portal. but when Webjobs are added in same solution then these files are missing. I'm checking this files from Azure portal and selecting the App service > Advanced tools > Kudu > CMD > site > wwwroot. I suppose these files are missing now that's the reason the App service is breaking.

Comment: @Angular, How about the result when you run this MSBuild command line without Azure devops, just using MSBuild command line in your local? If you still have this issue, so that we could narrow the scope of this issue.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT yes sure, I'll try that locally. but before that is the Azure Devops steps are correct to generate the Nupkg for Octopus? or There is some issue with MSBuild arguments for the project.